SSIS Script load Error MS Jet OleDB provider is not registered on local machine but it is
I have a SSIS package that has some c# script modules in it that manipulates an Access database file.  I am using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and the package runs fine on my dev box with no errors or wwarnings.  However when we deploy it to a Windows Server2012 R2 running under a SQL Server 2016 I am getting the "'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" error.  I believe this to be in error because we have other software running using the same drivers.  I have written a c# test app that is replicating the exact code in the script task and it performs without error so I know the driver is actually registered to the local machine.
I have reinstalled the driver which doesn't resolve it.  I feel like its is in the way the SSIS package may be handling the script task.  Has anyone seen such behavior?  I have searched and thus far only found suggestions that would indicate the driver wasn't installed.  This is a case where the driver is installed but it's throwing as if it wasn't.
The sequence is that the OleDbConnection is getting instantiated its when I go to open (dbConn.Open()) the connection (ConnectionState is closed on the instantiation) is when it is throwing the error.
using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(theAppSettings.DestDbConnString))
{
    if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        dbConn.Open();
    }
}

Edited 4/09/2024
This SSIS package has been built using both VS2012 and VS2019, have tried both the *.mdb and the *.accdb file versions utilizing both the JET 4.0 and the ACE 12.0 drivers

Try to run that package as 32-bit. Overall, it is better to start using Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider.

try install MDAC

The package is running in 32 bit mode, MDAC is installed, even switching to the ACE OLEDB provider the same error is being kick up.  The code that is in the script file has been put in a stand alone application and runs fine, however the functionality is needed in the SSIS package

If you create a package- or project-level connection and then use it from inside the Script task, via Dts.Connections collection, does that work?

Thanks Roger; haven't tried that approach until now.  Unfortunately I still get the error.  Even when just using the drag and drop controls from the SSIS tool the error crops up.  I know the driver is registered as I am able to use it through a simple c# application without error.  I have the simple app to where it can use both the JET & ACE driver.
